# Merge the values of several rows into a single field

Tags: mysql

I'm updating a TableA from another TableB with this MySQL script :

```
UPDATE TableA
JOIN TableB ON TableB.misc = TableA.id
SET TableA.fieldname = TableB.fieldname;
```

`TableB` may have many row where we can found `TableB.misc = TableA.id`, so I need to include this values row on the `TableA.fieldname` with a comma-separated :

**TableB:**

```
+------+-----------+
| misc | fieldname |
+------+-----------+
|   1  |    123    |
+------+-----------+
|   1  |    456    |
+------+-----------+
|   1  |    789    |
+------+-----------+
```

**Needed result on TableA:**

```
+---------+----------------+
|   id    |    fieldname   |
+------+-------------------+
|    1    |   123,456,789  |
+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: No, no, no, no! Never put multiple values in a single column!

Comment: @juergend _Sometimes_ denormalization is a benefit. If you ever download [S.O. database dump](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/10/how-to-download-the-stack-overflow-database-via-bittorrent/), you can find Posts.Tags field there. It can be used to avoid unnecessary JOINs. Not intended for filtering, of course.

Comment: @artoodetoo: Yes, there are a few times when this is OK. But I am sure that in this beginner question it is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you should group it before joining:

```
UPDATE TableA
JOIN (
    SELECT misc, GROUP_CONCAT(fieldname) grouped_fieldname
    FROM TableB GROUP BY misc) TableB ON TableB.misc = TableA.id
SET TableA.fieldname = TableB.grouped_fieldname;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`, and use an explicit cast on the numeric field to be aggregated (if it be numeric):

```
INSERT INTO TableA (id, fieldname)
SELECT misc, GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(fieldname AS CHAR(50)) ORDER BY fieldname)
FROM TableB
GROUP BY misc;
```

**Edit:**

I don't actually know whether any data already exist in the A table.  Even if it does, it might be faster to just truncate that table and run the insert I am suggesting.